# Mysql: RENAME TABLE IF EXISTS

Tags: mysql

This `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS` works, too bad that `RENAME TABLE IF EXISTS` doesn't work.

Can anyone suggest a solution for this query?

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF EXISTS video_top_day TO video_top_day_for_delete' at line 1
```

query:

```
RENAME TABLE IF EXISTS video_top_day TO video_top_day_for_delete
```

Comment: Which version of Mysql server is involved in? What is error message/code?

Comment: @rkosegi which version of mysql would need to be involved to not throw an error ?
IF EXISTS doesn't exist in mysql rename syntax..

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I've managed to execute a code that always works and generates no errors when the table doesn't exist:

```
SELECT Count(*)
INTO @exists
FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_schema = [DATABASE_NAME]
    AND table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
    AND table_name = 'video_top_day';

SET @query = If(@exists>0,
    'RENAME TABLE video_top_day TO video_top_day_for_delete',
    'SELECT \'nothing to rename\' status');

PREPARE stmt FROM @query;

EXECUTE stmt;
```

When you don't want to replace `[DATABASE NAME]` manually you can use the following variable

```
SELECT DATABASE() INTO @db_name FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: I will use similar approach. +1

Comment: Changed answer owner.

Comment: Works well, though I recommend you also check the that table you're renaming to doesn't already exist.  That will make the function idempotent.

Answer (score 14):

First create table `IF NOT EXISTS`. Then `RENAME` it, so it will always exist!

Otherwise, rename the table, and if it doesn't exist just handle the error.

It is obvious, but it works.

Comment: I wouldn't use IF NOT EXISTS. :D Mate you are like Captain Obviousness.

Comment: I will better create another query in a chain, to check if such table exists. But handling error will work too. Hmm maybe even better than checking, i can skip to next chain sequence.

Comment: This isn't great advice. If the old table exists, then you've just created a new, empty table where you want the old one to be. If the new one exists and you create the old one, then you have to drop it. You'd have to script this. If you are gonna script it, you may as well use a smarter check to see which table does exist and then take the appropriate action.

Answer (score 13):

There's no official solution yet. There has been [feature request](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=4754) submitted in 2004, never closed

Comment: Thanks mate, so i guess i'll have to execute another query before renaming SHOW TABLES LIKE 'video_top_day'. I'll accept your answer soon.

Answer (score 7):

Eight years after your question, MariaDB added the exact syntax you want in version 10.5.2: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/rename-table/

> `IF EXISTS`
> <sup>MariaDB starting with 10.5.2</sup>
> If this is directive is used, one will not get an error if the table to be renamed doesn't exist.

Comment: Yet another case of MariaDB picking up the slack after Oracle fell asleep on the job.

Answer (score 2):

```
create table table2 like table1;
insert into table2 select * from table1;
drop table table1;
```

Comment: this doesn't solve the problem. what if table1 doesn't exist? also, you are copying an entire table into another just to change its name!

Comment: Change `CREATE TABLE` to `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` and you have a fair solution.

Comment: @MarcusAdams no, you have not. This will not solve the problem that table1 might not exist. Furthermore this will not copy triggers or foreign keys.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to keep variables you can do also this:

```
DELIMITER $$
IF EXISTS (SELECT *
                     FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
                     WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = database()
                     AND  TABLE_NAME = 'oldname')
THEN
    RENAME TABLE oldname to newname;
END if;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

You can even further create a function if you want to reuse it

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with PL/SQL, then you can check for existence of table by querying information_schema.columns and based on this perform rename

Answer (score 0):

a workaround :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS video_top_day;
RENAME TABLE video_top_day TO video_top_day_for_delete
```

it creates an empty table if not exists !

Answer (score 0):

```sql
DELIMITER ;;
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS renameTableIfExists;;
CREATE PROCEDURE renameTableIfExists(IN tbl VARCHAR(255), IN toTbl VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
SELECT DATABASE() INTO @db_name;
SELECT Count(*) INTO @exists FROM information_schema.tables 
  WHERE table_schema = @db_name
    AND table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
    AND TABLE_NAME = tbl;

IF @exists > 0 THEN
   SET @dropToTbl = CONCAT("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ", toTbl); PREPARE dropToTbl FROM @dropToTbl; EXECUTE dropToTbl;
   SET @renameTbl = CONCAT("RENAME TABLE ", tbl, " to ",  toTbl); PREPARE renameTbl FROM @renameTbl; EXECUTE renameTbl;
   SELECT @tbl, @toTbl;
ELSE   
   SELECT 'Table not exists';
END IF;
END;;
DELIMITER ;

CALL renameTableIfExists('Tags', 'Tags2');
```