# Sqlite if Table Exists Then Rename

Tags: sqlite

Amazing, I expected to google and find an answer to this within a few seconds, but I've now spent 1/2 hour and tried many methods:

I need to rename a table if it exists, here's a couple of attempts:

```
var sql = "IF NOT EXISTS 'zones' ALTER TABLE 'sensors' RENAME TO 'zones';";
var sql = "ALTER TABLE if exists 'sensors' RENAME TO 'zones';";
```

Any idea how I can achieve this ??

Comment: Check out the top voted answer to this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9279619/mysql-rename-table-if-exists

Comment: @Paddyd SQLite is not MySQL.

Comment: What about : `sqlite> ALTER TABLE  if exists sensors RENAME TO zones;`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alter table doesn't contain any such syntax: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html

Simplest way of going about this would be to have a [query finding out if the table exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601151/how-do-i-check-in-sqlite-whether-a-table-exists), and if this returns a value then alter the table name

Comment: Thanks, that's what I ended up doing.

Comment: Can someone provide a complete example that has both the existence check and the renaming?