# RENAME table if target table does not exist

Tags: mysql, sql

I work with a legacy system and there are multiple batches that are executed after one another. In each of these batches there should be a rename of a table, although this rename should only happen once.

So, there could be:

```
RENAME TABLE oldName TO newName
```

in batch1 and batch2. However, in batch2 it would be best if this statement could just be ignored. Of course, it would be more clean to just memorize if the statement has been executed but this clean solution is near to impossible in the current code base.

So, I would like a MySQL solution that basically says: If table newName does not exist, then execute the rename command. Otherwise, do nothing and also do not send an error message.

Is this possible? If yes, how?

Comment: Why not just attempt the rename? If the destination name already exists, the rename will fail.

Comment: The statement throws an exception then. I could catch and ignore this specific one but there is a list of statements that is executed and this rename statement is just one of them, so I would have to put some extra code in to check whether it is a statement whose error should be ignored... Of course, this is possible, but some nice MySQL code would be shorter and a bit easier to read

Comment: I don't know of a way to do this without a stored proc, which won't be much nicer sadly. Someone else might though :)

Comment: Okay, thank you anyways! Maybe, I will stick to the Java solution, then... I will wait a bit and close this thread otherwise. Have a +1 for your effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been answered...

[Mysql: RENAME TABLE IF EXISTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9279619/mysql-rename-table-if-exists)

With the following code... (all credit to original author)

```
SELECT Count(*)
INTO @exists
FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_schema = [DATABASE_NAME]
AND table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
AND table_name = 'oldName';
SET @query = If(@exists=0,'RENAME TABLE oldName TO newName','SELECT \'nothing to rename\' status');
PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

When you don't want to replace [DATABASE NAME] manually you can use the following variable

```
SELECT DATABASE() INTO @db_name FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: works fine, will use variables in mysql now more frequently, thanks!